# Computing Directional Derivatives of Vector Fields

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

So in the context of differential geometry and covariant derivatives, I've seen the following formula for computing directional derivatives of a vector field $\mathbf X$.

$$D_{\mathbf V} \mathbf X = (\mathbf X(\mathbf{\alpha}(t)))'(0)$$

where $\mathbf \alpha$ is a curve with $\alpha(0) = P$ and $\alpha ' (0) = \mathbf V$.

But how does one use this in practice? Using the chain rule, you'd want the derivative of $\alpha$ times the derivative of $\mathbf X$ of $\alpha$. But if you use the dot product, that would give you a scalar result. It seems like it should be a vector result, since the derivative of a vector function has the same amount of dimensions as the original.

So how do you use this formula in practice?

Comment: If you have a vector field $X$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, you can think of it as a map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Its "derivative" (more correctly, its differential) is "morally" a matrix (more precisely is a map from the tangent bundle $T\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself and it is pointwise linear). If you apply the chain rule correctly, you get the product of a matrix and a vector, namely a vector.